# Mac Mail eternally "Preparing to Move Messages"

Tags: mail.app

I'm stuck moving messages on an Exchange account from the inbox to various folders using Apple Mail. I seem to be able to move individual messages but when I select a whole bunch (say 80) from the Inbox via a search function and bulk-drag them to the folder I want, the program hangs on "Preparing to Move Messages: 1 of 80" and doesn't go anywhere. If I quit Mail and open it again, it's as if I never tried to move the messages.

It appears to be somewhat random - sometimes no message comes up initially; in that case after a while (can be a long time depending on the number of messages) I get a quick "moving X of X messages" and it works, but if I quit too soon it doesn't actually move those messages either. But if the "Preparing to Move Messages" text comes up, they just never go.

I'm on Mojave 10.14.5 on a Mac Pro, using an Exchange email account.

I've checked [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315109/apple-mail-stuck-on-preparing-to-move-messages) but it doesn't seem to describe my problem.